# Is there a difference between a 32-bit .NET application and a 64-bit .NET application?

Tags: c#, .net

My understanding is that a .NET application is platform independent, so pure .NET code should run either on a x86 or on a 64-bit machine. Unless your .NET code call some native code, then it is platform dependent. Is that true?

Comment: Not really, every .NET app runs lots of native code.  And there's lots of native code that's available in both flavors.  The operating system is the best example.  Followed by the CLR and the jitter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) applications can be compiled as targeting x86, x64, or "Both". Typically, you'd target just one platform if you rely on a COM control that is not available for the other platform, etc.

Answer (score 9):

Your code can be compiled to be fully platform independent, or you can target a specific platform. The standard recommendation is to leave libraries architecture-neutral (that is, "Any CPU") and target x86 for executables. The reasons why Visual Studio 2010 uses this approach by default are explained here: [AnyCPU executables are usually more trouble than they're worth](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmbyers/archive/2009/06/09/anycpu-exes-are-usually-more-trouble-then-they-re-worth.aspx):

> 1. Running in two very different modes (x64 and x86) increases product complexity and the cost of testing.
> 2. 32-bit tends to be (a little) faster anyway.
> 3. Some features aren't available in x64.
> 4. If more than 4 GB address space would be useful, the right thing to do is to target *just* x64 and avoid the cost of supporting two platforms.

Of course, if you just target x86 then your code would still run on x64 through [WoW64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64).

Comment: I am very confused for the default behavior for executable. target to x86?

Comment: Yes, executables target x86.  Create a new solution in VS2010, then add a console application, a Windows Forms application, a WPF application and a class library.  If you then view the configuration manager (right click the solution, it's in the context menu), you'll see that the applications are all configured for x86, whilst the class library is set for AnyCPU.  This can be particularly annoying if you accidentally create an AnyCPU build (as I did a few months back) - your executables won't be built, as they don't have a valid configuration for AnyCPU by default.

Comment: x86 means it compiles strictly 32bit, x64 means it compiles strictly 64bit and AnyCPU means it compiles 32bit on a 32bit OS and 64bit on a 64bit OS. If you make any calls to COM/PInvoke, you need to target the correct arch because COM/PInvoke use pointers instead of references. I could be slightly off, but that's the general idea. P.S. 64bit gets access to extra CPU registers, so code may be faster and all 64bit ints can be calculated in 1 cycle. So any Int64 variables will run faster.

Comment: @Bengie Plus you might need x64 if you have vast memory requirements - although in most cases you've probably got a memory leak ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, what you say is true. Pure [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) code is platform independent ("Any CPU" in Visual Studio) unless external libraries (COM and [P/Invokes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) as far as I know) is used. Then your platform must match the one used to build the external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The article *[Back to Basics: 32-bit and 64-bit confusion around x86 and x64 and the .NET Framework and CLR](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasics32bitAnd64bitConfusionAroundX86AndX64AndTheNETFrameworkAndCLR.aspx)*  explains the differences pretty well.